# SSRS - Export / Print Report in Custom Font Style Issue

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts, ms-word, export

We are using custom font style in our SSRS reports. The custom font is showing correctly on the Development machine, ReportServer, and also on the Company Portal. When I export the report to PDF, again the custom font is showing correctly.

However, when I export the report to MS Word document, the font goes back to default (Arial or TimesNewRoman, etc). Surprisingly, even in the MS Word document, the custom font is showing properly in the Chart but not anywhere else in the report. The Tablix data, headers, etc. shows default font.

Can someone please share if you had similar experience? Any thoughts, inputs, suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: the chart is a graphic this is probably why it remains.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the reply !

Yes, I agree that the static image or graphic will show the expected font style. However, the testing team's observation is that it was working properly earlier and now it is not working as expected. I am not quite sure if it is a product limitation or if there is any workaround to fix this issue.

We have also tested by installing the font on the user pc, and we are aware that it works fine.

We are currently not planning to ask each and every end user to install the custom font to make this wrok.

I am still open for any tips, tricks, suggestions.. if any... :)

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

The chart is rendered as a graphic on the server. Since the server has the custom font the graphic renders with that font and it looks like the result you want. When the text is sent to the report, it has the font to be used as part of it. However, this then gets rendered on the client computer, so it will only render with that custom font if the custom font exists on the client computer; otherwise it will fall back to a default font like Arial as you are seeing.

The only way to get the text to render in your custom font on the client computer is to have that font installed on the client computer.

Your only other option is to render the entire report as an image on the server, which has the custom font, but this may not be what you are after if you are exporting into Word. Do you get your custom font rendered if you use the TIFF export option?